# How to dynamically add keys and values in python

Tags: python

how to dynamically insert keys into an existing python dictionary, input is the .json file and the output in a .csv file.

this is the input in the .json file

```
[{"FIRSTNAME":"barc","EMAIL":"jahg@jh.com","ADDRESS":"gyuyj"},
{"FIRSTNAME":"rth","EMAIL":"tht@thuyj.com","ADDRESS":"ytju"},
{"FIRSTNAME":"trhy","EMAIL":"klo@pyu.com","ADDRESS":"trght"},
{"FIRSTNAME":"ghy","EMAIL":"ytj@uki.com","ADDRESS":"ukyk"}]
```

output is required as .csv file(in each row its specified columns should be added)

```
"FIRSTNAME":"barc","rth","trhy","ghy"
"EMAIL":"jahg@jh.com","tht@thuyj.com","klo@pyu.com","ytj@uki.com"
"ADDRESS":"gyuyj","ytju","trght","ukyk"
"LASTNAME":"rgrg","thjuh","sygrbuir","yugfb"
"SALARY":"5665","5476","4565","5677"
```

as shown the difference between input file and output, lastname and salary are added.
similarly others fields should be added dynamically to the corresponding columns(even if it is given from other file).

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking a question here?

Comment: The output you are giving is not a CSV file. Your format will break pretty much all CSV importers. If you transpose the data (flip x and y) you can add a header line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
my_list = [{"FIRSTNAME":"barc","EMAIL":"jahg@jh.com","ADDRESS":"gyuyj"},
{"FIRSTNAME":"rth","EMAIL":"tht@thuyj.com","ADDRESS":"ytju"},
{"FIRSTNAME":"trhy","EMAIL":"klo@pyu.com","ADDRESS":"trght"},
{"FIRSTNAME":"ghy","EMAIL":"ytj@uki.com","ADDRESS":"ukyk"}]
my_dict = {}
for x in my_list:
    for key, value in x.items():
        my_dict[key] = my_dict.get(key, []) + [value]
```

my_dict content:

```
>>> my_dict
{'EMAIL': ['jahg@jh.com', 'tht@thuyj.com', 'klo@pyu.com', 'ytj@uki.com'], 'FIRST
NAME': ['barc', 'rth', 'trhy', 'ghy'], 'ADDRESS': ['gyuyj', 'ytju', 'trght', 'uk
yk']}
```

Now import to csv file:

```
with open("your_file", "w") as f:
    for key,value in my_dict.items():
        f.write("{}:{}".format(key, ",".join(value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to 2 python modules json and csv. Follow steps

- Use json module to read the json file.
- And use csv module to write into csv file. While writing you need to do the trick, add whatever new information/column you want to add in the csv.